# Empty array in multi class project returning null after receiving data when called upon

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having an issue that has been giving me a an error saying `java.lang.StackOverflowError: null`. My program is sort of like a lottery, a random number is chosen, and based off the number, your item is chosen from a array. Now this works all handy and dandy, but when i try to insert the item received into an inventory. I get that error. Im pretty sure i set up my class wrong but i don't know how to construct an array in a separate class that receives data from another class, and returns the data back to the same class. Enough chit chatting, heres what my code looks like so far. (please dont mind the extra variables as this is a cropped portion of my code)

```
public class inventory {
   private int inventorymain;
   public String[] inventorymain()  {
      String[] inventorymain;
      return inventorymain();
   }
}


    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class glue {

       public static void main(String [] args) { 
          inventory inv = new inventory();
          allskins a = new allskins();
          Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
          int selection = 0;
          int invcount = -1;
          Random rand = new Random();
          do {
             System.out.println(d.menue());
             selection = s.nextInt();
             if (selection == 1) {
                invcount++;
                int random = rand.nextInt(208);
                System.out.println("You opend a: ");
                System.out.println(a.allskins()[random]);
                System.out.println("Your item has been put in your inventory, select inventroy from the menue to view all items.");
                System.out.println("");
                inv.inventorymain()[invcount] = (a.allskins()[random]);
              }
          }while (selection != 6);
      }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: what are you doing inventarymain() is to just call the same method again. Instead you should return `new String[<array_size>]`

Comment: The array size depends on how many item the player recieves (which is random)

Answer (score 1):

You're entering infinite recursive loop calling `inventorymain()`

```
public class inventory {

    private int inventorymain;

    public String[] inventorymain()  {
        String[] inventorymain;
        return inventorymain(); // recursive call here without escape condition
    }

}
```

It's better to keep the method name and variable name different to avoid such cases.